# SVD with k smallest singular values

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any efficient way to find k *smallest* singular values of a large matrix?

Comment: Is this a _Mathematica_ question or a mathematics/algorithms question? For _Mathematica_ you could do `TakeSmallest[SingularValueList[m], k]`

Comment: Efficient way I mean not finding the whole SVD, but faster. There is a fast Mathematica method for finding a few largest SVD eigenvalues, but I don't see any method for finding a few smallest ones. I should also add that the matrix I have is a large sparse matrix, 10000x10000 with ~30000 non-zeros.

Comment: @Igor I am not sure that a method is implemented, or at least exposed and documented. Do you know of an *algorithm* that does what you want, i.e. calculates only the *smallest* singular values? If you do, then you can try to implement it and we can help you do so.

Comment: OK, I have found one way to do this: m2=Transpose[m].m is still sparse, then Eigenvalues[m2,-k] gives k smallest eigenvalues, which are squares of original SVD eigenvalues. I've tested this in Mathematica and it works pretty fast. Thank you for the advices, the question can be closed.

Comment: Assuming that all you eigenvalues of matrix m1  are positive. The Power Method gives the absolute largest eigenvalue, call it e1. Now we shift the eigenvalues by: m2= e1 IdentityMatrix - m1. The largest eigenvalue of m2 corresponds now to the smallest eigenvalue of m1. Finally you must undo the shiftingrds.

Comment: @DanielHuber That power-shift-power method is viable but requires to use `Transpose[m1].m1` to enforce that eigenvalues be real-valued (and correspond to squares of singular values).

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau  thank you Daniel